# Javascript: Why is classList not a property of Element.prototype

Tags: javascript

Why is `classList` not a property of `Element.prototype`? Because elements have a `classList` property, I would automatically assume it to be in the element's `prototype`, But apparently it's not. So where is it?

Chrome's console:

```
> Element.prototype.classList
undefined
> document.createElement().classList
DOMTokenList
```

Comment: Because every element has its own classlist? It's not a getter method, it's a data property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be a property of each `Element` instance, because if it was on the `Element` prototype then all elements would share the same class list, just as an `Array`'s `.length` property has to be on each array instance or all arrays would have the same length. The point of the prototype is that it is shared by all objects of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to **nnnnnn**'s answer, most instance variables are assigned in the constructor.

```
function foo(){
    this.bar = "baz";
}

foo.prototype.bar // undefined
new foo().bar // "baz"
```

Functions are added to the prototype (usually, but they can also be set in the constructor).

Comment: Thanks! This is a needed addition to @nnnnnn's answer.